# assertion to validate positive and negative test case for Login

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

**Code Body:**

```
    package testSteps;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import pageObjects.loginPage;
import utilities.XLUtils;

public class prc extends baseClass{
    
    @Test(dataProvider="LoginData")
    public void loginTestDDT(String uname, String pswd) throws InterruptedException {

        loginPage lp = new loginPage(driver);

        lp.enterUsername(uname);

        lp.enterPassword(pswd);

        lp.clickSignIn();
    
        try {
            lp.IsOpenChangeLogDisplayed();
            
                lp.closePopUp();
                lp.clickProfileIcon();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                lp.clickSignOut();
                driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                System.out.println("Login Successfully");
                
        } finally 
            
        {
            String actualMsg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='message']")).getText();
            System.out.println("actual Msg :"+actualMsg);
                String errorMsg= "Invalid password";
                
                    if(actualMsg.equals(errorMsg)) {
                            System.out.println("Test Case Passed");
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("Test Case Failed");
                    }
        }
    }

    @DataProvider(name="LoginData")
    String [][] getData() throws IOException{

        String path=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/test/java/testData/LoginData.xlsx";

        int rownum=XLUtils.getRowCount(path, "Sheet1");
        int colcount=XLUtils.getCellCount(path,"Sheet1",1);

        String logindata[][]=new String[rownum][colcount];

        for(int i=1;i<=rownum;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<colcount;j++)
            {
                logindata[i-1][j]=XLUtils.getCellData(path,"Sheet1", i,j);
            }

        }
        return logindata;
    }

}
```

I'm using this code for login flow testing. Try block code body will execute for positive test case and  Finally block code body is for negative Login Test case.
This code is working Fine and this is executing All the possible positive and negative test Cases.

**Problem:**
I want to validate that positive and negative cases executed Pass as per the expected outcome.
And also want to validate the negative test cases with Toaster message Output.
I want the result from this test that All the 6 test run with Different credentials executed successfully as per the expected result.
first run: with valid Credential Passed
remaining Run: with Invalid Credentials want to validate that toaster message is giving the same same msg what we expect and hence passed
overall test pss with 6 pass testrun.

```
**Console Window**
popUp is closed successfully
Login Successfully
actual Msg :Invalid password
Test Case Passed
actual Msg :Email not registered
Test Case Failed
actual Msg :Invalid password
Test Case Passed
actual Msg :Fields cannot be left blank !
Test Case Failed
actual Msg :Email not registered
Test Case Failed

===============================================
TestPlan
Total tests run: 6, Passes: 0, Failures: 6, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Tool Using: Maven Project, Eclipse, Selenium webDriver, TestNG, Java

Comment: Elaborate your problem. It is not clear to understand.

Comment: Elaborated problem and code Body. Please Check@NandanA

Comment: Let me put my understanding. You have a test and in try block validating positive case and in finally block validating negative case. You parametrized the data with 6 different credentials and your code is successful. You want to use assertion to fail the test case if the expected result doesn't match. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. for positive run True positive Assert validation and for Negative test run situation like false positives Assert validation @NandanA

Answer (score 0):

Test will be failed when assertion fails.

Asserts that two objects are equal. If they are not, an
error is thrown with the given message

```
 String actualMsg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='message']")).getText();
 Assert.assertEquals("Test Case Failed","Invalid password", actualMsg);
```

Comment: Srry, it is Not Worked for me. This Code works for me--> if(actualMsg.equals(errorMsg1)) {
      Assert.assertTrue(true); 
      System.out.println("Failed1");
         }
     else if(actualMsg.equals(errorMsg2))
     {
          Assert.assertTrue(true);
          System.out.println(" Failed2");
        }
     else if(actualMsg.equals(errorMsg3))
     {
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
     System.out.println("Failed3");   }                                                                                                                 but I want to use Assert here in a proper manner.

Comment: String errorMsg1= "Invalid password";
    String errorMsg2= "Email not registered";
    String errorMsg3= "Fields cannot be left blank !";

Comment: Also thanks for your valuable time...!!!. And special thanks for your suggestions. @nandan

Answer (score 0):

You should add additional fields in your test data like [this example](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/excel.html#sheet-per-test-case), for instance, `errorMessage` your test data may look like:

```
userName, password, errorMessage
validuser1,validpwd, 
validuser2,validpwd, 
validuser1,invalidpwd, Invalid password
invaliduser1,validpwd, Invalid user or password
,validpwd, Fields cannot be left blank!
```

in your test case you can check if error message exist then it should display error message otherwise login successful.

```
    @Test(dataProvider="LoginData")
    public void loginTestDDT(String username, String password, String errorMessage) throws InterruptedException {

        loginPage lp = new loginPage(driver);

        lp.enterUsername(uname);

        lp.enterPassword(pswd);

        lp.clickSignIn();


        if("".equalsIgnoreCase(errorMessage){
            lp.IsOpenChangeLogDisplayed();
            
                lp.closePopUp();
                lp.clickProfileIcon();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                lp.clickSignOut();
                driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                System.out.println("Login Successfully");
                
        } else {
            String actualMsg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='message']")).getText();
            System.out.println("actual Msg :"+actualMsg);

            Assert.equals(actualMsg,errorMessage);
        }
    }
```

You can also utilize [open source framework for selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/ecosystem/).  Below is example using [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io)

```
@QAFDataProvider(dataFile = "/src/test/java/testData/LoginData.xls")
@Test(dataProvider="LoginData")
public void loginTestDDT(Map<String, Object> testData) throws InterruptedException {
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage();
        loginPage.doLogin(testData.get("userName").toString(), testData.get("password").toString());

        String errorMessage = testData.get("errorMessage").toString();
        if(StringUtils.isBlank(errorMessage){
            //validate login successful
        }else{
            loginPage.getErrorEle().verifyVisible();
            loginPage.getErrorEle().verifyText(errorMessage);
        }
}
```